# How to tell what gcc/autotools options from CFLAGS also go in LDFLAGS?

Tags: gcc, ld, autotools, ldflags

I have some `-f` compiler options in `CFLAGS` like `-fsanitize=address` and someone suggested to me a while ago that I also put those options in `LDFLAGS` so I did. It hasn't caused any problems.

My question is how can I tell what compiler options from `CFLAGS` also should go in `LDFLAGS`? Is it just the `-f` prefixed options? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have some -f compiler options in CFLAGS like -fsanitize=address and
>   someone suggested to me a while ago that I also put those options in LDFLAGS
>   so I did. It hasn't caused any problems.

Not only it won't cause any problems but that's the only correct way to build sanitized program.

> My question is how can I tell what compiler options from CFLAGS
>   also should go in LDFLAGS? Is it just the -f prefixed options?

It won't hurt if you simply do

```
LDFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

Compiler driver (`/usr/bin/gcc`) knows which high-level options are for the linker so unnecessary options will be simply filtered out. In case you wonder how this happens, run gcc with `-dumpspecs` flag:

```
$ gcc -dumpspecs
...
*link_command:
%{!fsyntax-only:%{!c:%{!M:%{!MM:%{!E:%{!S:    %(linker) %{!fno-use-linker-plugin:%{!fno-lto:     -plugin %(linker_plugin_file)     -plugin-opt=%(lto_wrapper)     -plugin-opt=-fresolution=%u.res     %{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%:pass-through-libs(%(link_gcc_c_sequence))}}     }}%{flto|flto=*:%<fcompare-debug*}     %{flto} %{fno-lto} %{flto=*} %l %{no-pie:} %{pie:-pie} ...
```

This looks a bit ugly but in reality that's just a mini-language for flag translation. Syntax details are given [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.0/gcc/Spec-Files.html) (although I seriously doubt that you need need to know about them).